# read the content of the current page opened page of PDF file

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf

I'm trying to read data and attributes from an opened PDF file which is on screen.
Is there a way of attaching to running acrobat reader and manipulating data from it ?

Comment: Does it have to be two separate processes? There are definitely some libraries around to open a PDF, display it and gather the data. Attaching to another process and reading something is tough if you don't know anything about the interiors of the process. Have a look [here](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries).

Comment: Yes I want to be able to get data from an already opened file which is already on screen.

Comment: This will be pretty tough and I have no serious idea how you would start this. If Acrobat Reader does not provide an interface then you won't be able to do that.

Comment: You clearly have not done some research on this topic. [A quick google](http://bit.ly/12kEZ2J) found you an answer. However, see my answer below...

Answer (score 0):

Attaching to another process means that you will have to handle a lot of inter-process-communication (IPC). Apart from that, you don't know what Acrobat Reader looks like inside. So you cannot simple ask it to deliver you some bytes.
Instead, you should use one of the many libraries to open, display and read PFD-files like [iTextSharp](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries/itextsharp). I am certain that these will serve purposes well.

There are many more libraries [available](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries), you should have a look at [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1).

Comment: While I also would recommend iTextSharp for numerous tasks involving PDF manipulation, it unfortunately cannot display them.

Answer (score 0):

I have never done it my self, but a quick look around I found that the Acrobat Reader (assuming that is what you are talking about) has an [API](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/downloads.html) which ([by looking at its documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/10/Acrobat10_HTMLHelp/index.html)) has an IPC module which will be the closest to what you are asking for.